# django-templated-email doen't works on heroku

Tags: python, django, web-services, heroku, github

I've installed succesfully https://github.com/bradwhittington/django-templated-email.git, and it works smoothly on my local server, but, when I upload my app to a heroku repo that I have, when it get's to the sending email, the browser shows  internal server error.

I think this is because it tries to read code from where "pip" installed the package, and that data path doesn't exists on heroku.

**What I need to know:**
How can I make it to work in my heroku server?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you specified the below in your `requirements.txt` file for `pip` to know where to install it from?

The below points to the latest commit. If the developer has packaged the file as a egg, you can use that too.

```
git+git://github.com/bradwhittington/django-templated-email.git/62a291004cb21e50409b276bcbd79ae9808aace9
```

So if the missing package is the reason for your error, adding the above to requirements.txt should fix it

Comment: That's possible, I'll try it. Thanks a lot!